# How to render a pixelated, occluded wireframe with freestyle?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, wireframe

I'd like to combine these features:

1. The pixelated look of a wire material with anti-aliasing disabled.
2. Proper occlusion of hidden lines.

A wireframe material produces the first feature, freestyle produces the second. Can a line set be created that produces neither double pixels nor gaps? Line thickness alone does not seem to be the answer.

There is the trick with two materials and z-offset, but I have trouble getting a really clean solution at the outline of the object. So a freestyle solution would be best.

[image]

The main problem is that freestyle (to the right) produces double pixels:

[image]

Comment: How about rendering the wire, then using an image editor to remove antialiasing?

Comment: @CharlesL Why not just disable antialiasing in *Render settings > anti-aliasing*?

Comment: I added a second picture to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Blender [OpenGL viewport rendering](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/quick_render.html#the-purposes-of-opengl-rendering) for this.

- Go to edit mode, activate edge-select and Z-Clipping:

[image: viewport settings]

- Go to User Preferences, System, then disable all lights and make the final one black (color and specular, in my screenshot, only the specular ones are set to black).

[image: light settings]

- Go to the Theme settings, 3D View and set selected edges to white and selected faces to black.

[image: theme settings]

- Select everything and press the "OpenGL render active viewport" (3D view header, the left one in the screenshot).

[image: viewport render]

To remove other lines such as lamps you can enable *Only render* in *3D view > Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Display > Only render* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle the [3D manipulator](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/manipulators.html).

If the background is a problem, you can put a face there or also make it black in the theme settings.

AA has to be disabled, otherwise you will get smooth lines.

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Crazy, but close enough. Although I'd suggest turning wireframe on in the object's drawing options, so several objects are possible. Enabling all edges helps as well. Great Trick

Comment: That's possible, but keep in mind that turning Wire on in the object's drawing options will hide edges on flat surfaces, so you don't really get a full wire.

Comment: That's what 'draw all edges' in the object's display panel is for.

Comment: Ah, forgot that existed. Very good.

Comment: Alternatively your could just set the _Horizon Color_ to white, use a white shadeless material, change viewport shading to _Texture_ and invert the image in the compositor.

Comment: Just to note that the new [*Hidden wire*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.69/Modeling#Viewport:_Hidden_Wire) draw option would be perfect for this if you want to use the openGL render.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this with a wireframe material using [this method](http://www.blendtuts.com/2010/08/how-to-render-wireframes.html) (see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2785/599)):

1. Disable anti-aliasing in *render settings*

   [image]
2. Create a material wire material, enable transparency and increase the *Z offset*:

   [image]
   [image]
3. Create another material for your object and make it pure black:

   [image]
4. Assign the second (black) material to all the faces (<kbd>Tab</kbd>*> edit mode* <kbd>A</kbd>*> select all > Assign*.
5. Set the world color to black:

   [image]
6. Render:

   [image]
   [image]

Note that sometimes with low resolution renders you may have to increase the Z offset even more to prevent gaps in the edges.

Comment: your render exactly outlines my problem. you have a lot of double pixels there. Adjusting line thickness isn't the answer. I do know the freestyle basics. Sorry if I haven't made myself clear enough, although I mentioned double pixels.

Comment: @Haunt_House Oops, sorry. I don't know how I missed that :P

Comment: I have to apologize. Hm, the editing is sometimes scary. Although the question is now more technically correct, there was a reason I used the phrase 'perfect wireframe'. Not very precise, I admit. But that's what the body is for.