# wireframe render over an object with the subdivision surface wireframe?

Tags: wireframe

Is there a way to render an object with a subdivision surface modifier with a wireframe which is the original geometry as well as the wires that make the subdivision surface?

Example:
[image]

This wireframe here is curved. What if there was displayed the straight wireframe. The wires that make are made by the subdivision surface. Thats what I want to achieve. How to do it?

What I mean is - How to render the curved wireframe (which is the original geometry with the straight wireframe (which is the wireframe the is made by the subdivision surface)?

Comment: Are you saying you want the head to be rendered with the wireframe showing? If so, that is possible.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I think he wants to render the high-poly head, with a quasi-low-poly wireframe; the wireframe should look pretty much like the edges of the low-poly head, but with nice curves like the high-poly head.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2372/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Rendering curved wireframes:

### Blender Internal

You can either use freestyle or a wireframe material, see [Rendering with wireframe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2784/599).

If you use a wireframe material, make sure *Optimal display* is enabled on the modifier, otherwise all the edges generated by the subserf will be rendered as wires (they won't be curved).

[image]

### Cycles

To do this in cycles, you could use two scenes, one for the cycles render and another to render the wireframe with one of the BI techniques.

To get a BI wireframe material to render with a transparent background (for combining with a cycles render), just set the second material to *Masking alpha*:

[image]

And set *Alpha* to *Transparent* in *Render settings > Shading*:

[image]

---

## Original answer

*OP clarified the question, making this no longer relevant. As far as I can tell, that is..*

If you want to do this in the viewport/opengl render, just enable *Draw All edges* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

And make sure *Optimal display* is disabled in the subserf modifier:

[image]