# How to make a render with a curved along with straight wireframe in cycles?

Tags: wireframe

How to make a render with a curved along with a straight wireframe in cycles?

Curved - The original geometry; 
Straight - The wires the are created by the subdivision surface;

I figured how to do this using the image editor but the wires of the wireframe are not equal because the thickness of the wires depend on the scaling of the poligons.

Comment: This is a very good question. He's asking if it's possible to render a wireframe view where some of the "wires" are curved, based on the subsurf modifier.

Comment: @Keavon Unless I'm mistaken, he [already asked that question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9177/599).

Comment: Yes I have, but ob the other questions I was not quite clear.

Comment: @Vladimir Then edit the other question or ask for clarification on the answer or in the comments.

Comment: I can see that the question is pointed as unclear (whatever that is). The question - How to render a scene with both wireframes (the original geoetry, which is the curved one: And the second one, which is the wires that are made by the suvdivision surface)

Comment: And both to have different colour