# How to create a wireframe with pixelated lines

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, wireframe

I want to create a wireframe on top of my model that is not anti-aliased, and is only 1 pixel thick all the way around, like this:

[image]

Is this possible in modern blender? Freestyle and wireframe modifier both add anti-aliasing:

[image]

This can be remedied somewhat with some compositor tricks to limit it to 2 colors, but then the lines aren't an even thickness, which really bothers me.

This was [possible in blender 2.7 and earlier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-render-a-pixelated-occluded-wireframe-with-freestyle), but it seems impossible in 2.8-4